# How to run matplotlib python script from a different directory?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run a python/matplotlib plotting script from a different directory, and am getting an error concerning matplotlib import.

So in my data-containing directory I am running:

```
python /home/birac/SCRIPTS/plot.py data.txt
```

Where plot.py is:

```
#!/home/birac/anaconda2/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
xdata, ydata = np.loadtxt(fname=filename, comments='@', usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, color='gray', marker='.', markersize=0)
plt.savefig('graph.png')
```

However, it is giving me a weird error concerning my matplotlib import:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/birac/SCRIPTS/plot.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 69, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/birac/SCRIPTS/copy.py", line 17, in <module>
    extent possible) inserts *the same objects* into it that the
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ayeg_subs_100ns.pdb'
```

The I/O error refers to file 'ayeg_subs_100ns.pdb', which is not present in either directory.

Essentially it seems that instead of importing the python copy module, it is trying to find a script in the local directory called 'copy.py', which doesn't exist.

I can run the file from the same or another directory, but I'm curious as to why this is a issue from this particular directory.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: According to the traceback `/home/birac/SCRIPTS/copy.py` does exist.

Comment: I agree that it looks like that, but it definitely doesn't. It's possible that it did exist when I installed anaconda - could this be the issue?

Comment: Maybe `copy.pyc` or `copy.pyo` or `copy.whatever`.

Comment: Or in `/home/birac/SCRIPTS/__pycache__`

Comment: Yes, you're right. There's a copy.pyc present. Should I delete this?

Comment: Yes, that's what python finds when it looks for a `copy` module.

Comment: Yes, worked great. Thanks very much. I'll need to teach myself some more about pyc files I guess.